# Regarding calling inherited functions

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, methods

I have a base class called account. Three classes are inheriting from account. These classes are savings, checkings, and creditcard. In my main() I am trying to create a switch menu so that when the user selects 1 it will call makeDeposit(), which is part of account, but do so through savings. This way when the user chooses 3 it will call makeDeposit(), but do so through checkings. Here is the code I have written. I have declared object saving sa; and when I call makeDeposit I am trying to write it as sa.makeDeposit(). Here is the code:

```
int main ()
{
    saving sa;
    creditCard cca;
    checking ca;

    string n;
    int option;
    int exit = 1;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Checking Balance:" << " " << "          " << "Savings balance:" << " " << "          " << "Credit Card balance:" << " " << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << " (1) Savings Deposit " << endl;
    cout << " (2) Savings withdrawel " << endl;
    cout << " (3) Checking Deposit " << endl;
    cout << " (4) Write A Check " << endl;
    cout << " (5) Credit Card Payment " << endl;
    cout << " (6) Make A Charge " << endl;
    cout << " (7) Display Savings " << endl;
    cout << " (8) Display Checkings " << endl;
    cout << " (9) Display Credit Card " << endl;
    cout << " (0) Exit " << endl;
    cin >> option;

    do{

    switch ( option )

    {
        case 1 : double amtD;
                 cout << " Please enter how much you would like to deposit into savings " << endl;
                 cin >> amtD;
                 double sa.makeDeposit(double amtD);
                 break;
        case 2 : double makeWithdrawel();
                 break;
        case 3 : double makeDeposit();
                 break;
        case 4 : 
                 break;
        case 5 : 
                 break;
        case 6 : double makeWithdrawel();
                 break;
        case 7 : int display();
                 break;
        case 8 : int display();
                 break;
        case 9 : int display();
                 break;
        case 0 : exit = 0;
                 break;
        default : exit = 0;
                 cout << " ERROR ";
    }
    }
    while(exit==1);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my class saving :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "Account.h"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

class saving: public account
{
public :

    double doWithdraw(double amount);
    saving();
    saving(string itsName, long itsTaxID, double itsBalance);
}
```

and my class for account :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
class account {

public :
    void setName(string name); void setTaxID(long taxID); void setBalance(double balance);
    string getName(); long getTaxID(); double getBalance();
    double makeDeposit( double amount );
    account();
    account(string itsName, long itsTaxID, double itsBalance);
    int display();

private :
    string itsName;
    long itsTaxID;
    double itsBalance;

protected :
    double last10withdraws[10];
    double last10deposits[10];
    int numdeposits;
    int numwithdraws;

};
```

Any idea on what I am doing wrong??

Comment: What is the specific problem you are having/an example input for which you don't get the expected output (and what you actually get)?

Answer (score 1):

You're calling functions incorrectly. You do not need to include the types for the return value and parameters.

```
case 10: int function(); break;
```

is actually declaring a local function - **not** calling `function` as you expect.

Your switch statement should look something like below. Notice the absence of types in the calls to functions

```
switch ( option )
{
case 1 : double amtD;
    cout << " Please enter how much you would like to deposit into savings " << endl;
    cin >> amtD;
    sa.makeDeposit(amtD);
    break;
case 2 : makeWithdrawel();
    break;
case 3 : makeDeposit();
    break;
case 4 : 
    break;
case 5 : 
    break;
case 6 : makeWithdrawel();
    break;
case 7 : display();
    break;
case 8 : display();
    break;
case 9 : display();
    break;
case 0 : exit = 0;
    break;
default : exit = 0;
    cout << " ERROR ";
}
```

Comment: Thank you Captain Obvious. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The following code looks a bit weird.

```
cin >> amtD;
double sa.makeDeposit(double amtD);
break;
```

You are trying to declare a variable with the **double** keyword, but I think you want to do one of two things:

1. Just make the deposit without using the returned double from makeDeposit() for anything. In that case, just write the line like this (using the returned double is optional):

   sa.makeDeposit(amtD);
2. You want to make the deposit but also save some return information. Then you would probably do something like this (and use the new variable for something later).

   double justMadeDeposit = sa.makeDeposit(amtD);

It's some guesswork. Maybe you don't want the makeDeposit() function to return anything at all, and then you could declare it as **void** instead.

Comment: Actually that won't even compile.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: Oh, now I see what you mean. I'll fix it.